# Use a row on a DF as new columns name in another DF

Tags: pandas

I would like to replace some columns names of a DF with names in rows in another DF

```
import pandas as pd
df1=pd.DataFrame({'T2': [2,3],
          'T1': [4,5],
          'HO': [2,7]
          })

df2=pd.DataFrame({'T1' : ['cat'],
            'T2' :['dog']  
           })
```

How can I replace in df1 'T1' and 'T2' with 'dog and 'cat' that are in the df2 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use the easier way

```
print df2.iloc[0]

T1    cat
T2    dog
Name: 0, dtype: object

Solution:
df1 = df1.rename(columns=df2.iloc[0])

print df1
   HO  cat  dog
 0   2    4    2
 1   7    5    3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert `df2` to a `dict` that maps the column name to the row value using [df.to_dict](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html), then use the `dict` to rename the columns using [df.rename](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html). Here's how:

```
In [4]: df1 
Out[4]: 
   HO  T1  T2
0   2   4   2
1   7   5   3

In [5]: df2 
Out[5]: 
    T1   T2
0  cat  dog

In [6]: df2.to_dict(orient="records")
Out[6]: [{'T1': 'cat', 'T2': 'dog'}]

In [7]: df1.rename(columns=df2.to_dict(orient="records")[0])
Out[7]: 
   HO  cat  dog
0   2    4    2
1   7    5    3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use mapping:

```
 def mapping(x):
    return df2[x] if x in df2 else x

df1.columns=list(map(mapping, list(df1.columns)))

print(df1)

   dog  cat  HO
0    2    4   2
1    3    5   7
```